# Reference or proof for number of permutations of [2n] with longest increasing subsequence of length n.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, asymptotics

In [A267433](https://oeis.org/A267433) the result $a(n) \sim 16^n (n-1)! / (\pi e^2)$ is quoted as being from Vaclav Kotesovec with a link to [his page](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Vaclav_Kotesovec). However I can't find the result in any of those papers.

Does anyone know a reference or proof for this result?

Comment: Empirically it looks plausible, with a relative error which is $<1\%$ for $n >6$ (up to $74$) and diminishing as $n$ increases for $n>13$

Comment: It is not the first case where we do not get more

Comment: You could email him.

Comment: @brainjam I have tried that but no luck so far.

Comment: I believe that with enough patience, we can do this by inclusion-exclusion, but this does not seem fun enough for me to do it at the moment.

Comment: In https://oeis.org/A047874, Kotesovec points to a reference of Regev: Asymptotic values for degrees associated with strips of Young diagrams. I didn't looked if the asymptotic from A267433 can be derived easily from this asymptotic.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Can you elaborate? I don't see how $\frac{1}{\pi e^2}$ will follow.... You must mean some generating function circle method thing (after inclusion-exclusion).

Comment: @mathworker21 The first term of inclusion-exclusion, where we add up the number of permutations with an increasing subsequence in every possible position, gives us $\binom{2n}{n}^2 n! \sim 16^n (n-1)!/\pi$ from Stirling's approximation. Getting $1/e^2$ of that after we subtract and add some overlaps is a very common thing to see as the result of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @MishaLavrov thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be worked out pretty simply using the Robinson–Schensted correspondence.  One of the consequences of this correspondence is that the number of permutations on $m$ letters with longest ascending subsequence of length $k$ equals
$$\sum_{\lambda\vdash m,\ \lambda_1=k} \left(\frac{m!}{H(\lambda)}\right)^2,$$
where the sum is over all Young tableaux $\lambda$ with $m$ cells and first row of length $k$.  [[1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/longest-increasing-and-decreasing-subsequences/B5098D9BC8B226C575402B971852C05E)]  Here, a Young tableau is an array of cells arranged in rows whose length decreases from top to bottom, with each row having its leftmost edge in the same place,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\square \square \square \square \square \\
\square \square \\
\square 
\end{array}
$$
and $H(\lambda)$ is the product of the number of cells in each hook in $\lambda$, where a hook consists of a cell in the tableau together with all cells directly underneath and to its right.  You can write $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\cdots$ for the row lengths of the tableau and $\lambda'_1\ge\lambda'_2\ge\cdots$ for its column lengths.

Given this, if you want the number of permutations $a(n)$ on $2n$ letters with longest ascending subsequence of length $n$, you need to sum over $\lambda\vdash 2n$ with $\lambda_1=n$; but these tableaux are just the tableaux with $\lambda\vdash n$ with an extra row of length $n$ inserted at the top, so
$$a(n)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \left(\frac{(2n)!}{H(\lambda)\prod_{1\le i\le n} (n+1-i+\lambda'_i)}\right)^2.\qquad (1)$$
Here, the denominator consists of the product of the hook sizes for cells in the first row of the expanded tableau, together with the product $H(\lambda)$ of the hook sizes for the remainder of the tableau, and I am setting $\lambda'_k:=0$ if there are fewer than $k$ columns in $\lambda$, or, equivalently, $k>\lambda_1$.

You can use the correspondence to compute the total number of permutations on $n$ letters:
$$
n!=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \left(\frac{n!}{H(\lambda)}\right)^2
$$
so
$$
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\frac{1}{H(\lambda)^2}=\frac{1}{n!}.\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
Now split the sum (1) into piece A, where $\max(\lambda_1,\lambda'_1)<3\sqrt{n}$, and piece B, where $\max(\lambda_1, \lambda'_1)\ge3\sqrt{n}$.  The number of permutations on $n$ letters with a longest ascending subsequence of length $k$ or more is no more than
$$
\binom{n}{k}^2 (n-k)!,
$$
since you can specify such a permutation by picking $k$ positions and letters for the first portion of the ascending subsequence and an ordering of the remaining $n-k$ letters which fill the other $n-k$ positions.  Then
$$
\frac{1}{n!} \binom{n}{k}^2 (n-k)! \le \frac{n^k}{k!^2} \le \left(\frac{ne^2}{k^2}\right)^k
$$
but if $k=\lfloor 3\sqrt{n} \rfloor$, this vanishes as $n\to\infty$.  It follows that
$$
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n,\ \lambda_1\ge 3\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{H(\lambda)^2}=o{\left(\frac 1 {n!}\right)},
$$
and since $H(\lambda)$ is not changed by reflecting the tableau so that rows and columns are interchanged,
$$
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n,\ \max(\lambda_1,\lambda'_1)\ge 3\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{H(\lambda)^2}=o{\left(\frac 1 {n!}\right)},
\qquad\qquad(3)
$$
and piece B doesn't contribute much to (1).
On the other hand, if $\lambda$ is in piece A, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{1\le i\le n} (n+1-i+\lambda'_i) &=& n! \prod_{1\le i\le n} (1 + \frac{\lambda'_i}{n+1-i}) \\
&=& n! e^{\sum_i \lambda'_i/n} (1 + o(1)) \\
&=& n!\  e (1 + o(1)),\qquad\qquad (4)
\end{eqnarray*}
uniformly in $\lambda$.  Combining (1), (2), (3) and (4) gives
$$
a(n)=
\left(\frac{1}{n!}+o\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)\right) \left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!e}\right)^2(1+o(1))
+o\left(\frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\right)^2\right).
$$
Dividing by $n!$, simplifying and using Stirling's approximation on the factorials, and multiplying back by $n!$ then gives
$$
a(n)=\left(\frac{1}{\pi n} \frac{2^{4n}}{e^2} \cdot n!\right)\,(1+o(1)),
$$
which is what you want.

[1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/longest-increasing-and-decreasing-subsequences/B5098D9BC8B226C575402B971852C05E): "Longest Increasing and Decreasing Subsequences", C. Schensted, *Canadian Journal of Mathematics*, **13** (1961), pp. 179-191, DOI: https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1961-015-3

Comment: Since this is MSE and not MO, maybe add "by Stirling's approximation" (even in parentheses if you wish) to the very end of your answer?

Comment: OK.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I posted a related question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833644/proof-for-number-of-permutations-of-n2-with-longest-increasing-subsequence . Do you think there is a similarity clean proof ?